# How to prevent Activity from recreating fragments

Tags: android

I'm using `FragmentPagerAdapter` to display a `ListFragment` in the `OnCreate()` of my main Application class. Simply:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TripListFragment(), "Reissulista");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

`ViewPagerAdapter` is a bit extended `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `TripListFragment` is a `ListFragment`.

This works fine, but if the Application gets destroyed after being on the back for long the app crashes on reopening. The `ListFragment` accesses some data straight from the main Activity and the data is not loaded yet. However, the data gets loaded before I add the fragment to the adapter in `OnCreate`.

I've figured out that the problem is `super.OnCreate()` trying to rebuild the fragment from memory before rest of my `OnCreate` is done.

The question is, how can I prevent the `OnCreate` supermethod from recreating my stuff and just let me do it in the proper way. And should I? Would it be more proper to make the `ListFragment` retain the data it needs. However, if I do that, won't I get a duplicate fragment somewhere in memory when I create a new one?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but if the activity wants to recreate the fragment, you should not want to prevent it from doing that. Instead learn to work with it

Comment: You should worth within the constraints of the life cycle methods, not try to subvert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to change my ViewPagerAdapter implementation so that the fragments won't get remade on each oncreate. I had a list based implementation before, now I rely on the more usual implementation where the fragments are made on getItem() (if the don't already exist).

The problem with the fragments being recreated before their data was solved simply by moving super.oncreate() after the data creation.

Answer (score 1):

> "The ListFragment accesses some data straight from the main `Activity` and the data is not loaded yet."

This sounds like a problem - you shouldn't load the data until you KNOW it's there. I would use a listener or something to do this. Perhaps inside your Activity, if you are running an `AsyncTask` to load the data, you can tell the `Fragment` to display it like this:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     //TODO: Implement your own way
     ((MyFragment)getFragment()).displayData(result);
 }
```

Obviously this is a very broad explanation and will need to be customized to your problem, but if you can wait to display data until you can ensure it is there, you shouldn't have a crash.

Comment: I should have worder myself better. The data is loaded from sharedpreferences. No threads there, everything is done quickly on the UI thread. It's just the content array of the listview.

Comment: ahhh I see, my mistake. I'm gonna nuke this answer in a minute, I'll undelete it if I think of something else.. @Migzu

Comment: Changed my mind, undeleted for purpose of discussion.

Comment: No problem. I think the answer must be just under my nose. This should not be an unusual situation after all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rework your design so that you can access the data when you need to within the constraints of the lifecycle methods for both your activity and your fragment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setRetainInstance in fragments:

```
Class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   public MyFragment() {
       setRetainInstance(true);
   }

}
```

Mind that this solves the issue of fragments being recreated, activities will still be recreated as per the lifecycle. However data you already reference inside the fragment will still be there. You should not connect fragments and activities directly, I recommend the activity calling the fragment's particular method in onResume and/or onPause or onDestroy.